# why the code cause segmentation fault?

Tags: c++11

Below is the code:

```
vector<set<int>> sets;
set<int> myset{ 3, 5, 8, 2, 10, 9, 7, 15 };
set<int> newSet{ *myset.begin() };
sets.push_back(newSet);
set<int>::iterator it = myset.begin();
it++;
for (; it != myset.end(); it++)
{
    for (vector<set<int>>::iterator it1 = sets.begin(); it1 != sets.end(); it1++)
    {
        set<int> newSet1(*it1);      //LINE1
        sets.push_back(newSet1);     //LINE2
        it1->insert(*it);            //LINE3
    }

}
```

During the first time entering the second for loop, after `LINE2`, `it1` becomes a NULL, so `LINE3` causes `segmentation fault`. Why after `LINE2`, `it1` is gone?

`LINE2` copies `newSet1` into the vector sets. Will it copy the whole set or just the address of `newSet1`?

Answer (score 1):

The push_back changes sets, so it1 is no longer reliable.  A push_back copies the entire entry into the vector.

Accessing the vector via an index  ( e.g., sets[2] ) will work, but bounds are not checked, so be sure the index is within range before accessing.

Comment: That is too creepy. :-( A push_back is supposed to only make a copy of newSet1. Why it destroys newSet1?

Comment: It doesn't.  It doesn't destroy the entry that is put in the vector.

Comment: @John it doesn't destroy `newSet1` it invalidates `it1`. That is after the `push_back` iterator `it1` points to a wrong location and this causes undefined behaviour, in your case segfault.

Comment: it1 is not reliable because the push_back could completely change the vector.  (It might be recopied to another memory area to deal with the longer array.  There are no free lunches, even in STL.)

Comment: What I need is to change a vector during iterating the vector. There is no way to do it using iterator, right? How about using "for range loop"? like 'for(auto e : vec) {std::set e1(e); vec.puch_back(e1); }'. Will it work?

Comment: @John, I don't think so.  Maybe a regular for loop, access the vector via an index.

Comment: @John, an index is just a number, not an iterator.  It should work, as long as the loop checks the size of the vector each time.  An iterator is like a pointer, which is why they can get jazzed if the vector changes at all.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a subset of your code:

```
std::vector<T> sets;
for (auto it = sets.begin(); it != sets.end(); it++)
    sets.emplace_back();
```

The above code exhibits **undefined behavior** because we modify the vector, and then expect that the iterators to `sets` are still valid.

In particular, the iterators will become invalid when you perform an `insert()` and `size() == capacity()`.

#### About your other question:

> LINE2 copies newSet1 into the vector sets. Will it copy the whole set or just the address of newSet1?

It will call the copy constructor of `std::set<T>` and you will get a copy of the set that you passed as an argument to the `push_back()` call.